# form within alert box using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open an alert box (Javascript) with one input text and submit button, then on user click is submit to another page, its like a form with one input text, all the examples that given are modals examples, i just need an alertbox.

Comment: U can use `prompt('Your statement here')`.

Comment: Cool. Do you also have a question or did you just want to tell us what you are working on? This is a Q&A website, not a forum or blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code http://jsfiddle.net/va4sF/2/

```
var val = prompt('Please enter the search query');
if (val) {
    window.location.href='http://google.com?q=' + val + '#q=' + val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the prompt command.  You can read about it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt